# How can I create a DataType.DropDownList attribute in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, data-annotations

I do not want to use/create an extension helper like:

`@Html.EnumDropDownListhtmlHelper(...)`

My ViewModel should determine how it is rendered not the view!

`DataType` attribute has no `DropDownList`.

How can I create one in asp.net mvc 4.0 ?

Comment: Who wants to close this and why? Its a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

I completely disagree - You model is used to represent your data and data access layer, plus any Business Logic for persisting that data. Your DAL should be transferable to any other application, other than MVC (for e.g. a WPF app).

It your view and the HTML used that should decide how your data is rendered, NOT the model.

Your HTML Helper thus would handle your DropDownList (`HTML.DropDownListFor`).

Answer (score 0):

You could create EditorTemplate to use that **@Html.EnumDropDownListhtmlHelper(...)**
Then you will need to decorate your model enum property with UIHint attribute and pass the name of the EditorTemplate, since there is no DataType.DropDownList attribute.

Comment: "...since there is no DataType.DropDownList attribute..." but my question is about that.